# Type Error while executing the face recognition code

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, face-recognition

I'm working on with my face recognition project, but it throws an error when I run this line specifically

```
imgBackground[44:44 + 633, 808:808 + 414] = imgModeList[3]
```

Help me out to get rid of this error.

```
while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img_small = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    img_small = cv2.cvtColor(img_small, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    faceCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(img_small)
    encodeCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(img_small, faceCurFrame)

    for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, faceCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        faceDist = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        print("matches", matches)
        print("faceDis", faceDist)

        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDist)
        print("Match Index", matchIndex)

        if matches[matchIndex]:
            print("Known face was detected")
            print(studentsId[matchIndex])

    imgBackground[162:162 + 480, 55:55 + 640] = img
    imgBackground[44:44 + 633, 808:808 + 414] = imgModeList[3]
    # cv2.imshow("Webcam", img)
    cv2.imshow("Face Attendance", imgBackground)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Tony Alosius\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\main.py", line 52, in <module>
>     imgBackground[44:44 + 633, 808:808 + 414] = imgModeList[3]
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
> [ WARN:0] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (438) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
> ```

I have tried running this code after commenting the line which throws as error, only it makes an bug. But I hope I have made the correct slicing to fix the captured image on frame. Kindly please help me out to correct the bug.

Comment: Show us how `imgBackground` is created.

Comment: Show us the shape and dtype of each of imgBackground and imgModeList.  I suspect it is coming from imgModeList.